# struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes

Tags: python

I have a script that imports .milo_wii files from The Beatles: Rock Band game (inspiration of my username). When I import the materials however, I get an error of "*struct.error: unpack_From requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes*". This is the line that gives me the problem:

`mat_name_len  = unpack_from(">I", datastream, pos)[0]`

I have tried renaming the 0 to 4, but that doesn't work. I have tried other solutions online, but I don't see how I could format their solutions into my line of code. If someone could steer me in the right direction, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The script expects there to be four bytes in datastream at position pos, but there aren't. This is a logic error in the script, probably the format of the .milo_wii file is not completely understood and accounted for. You can't fix it by tweaking this one line.

Comment: I just fixed the error by replacing pos with 4, (with having to replace other lines). But I am now greeted with this error on line 30: if os.path.exists(filepath): (ValueError: stat: embedded null character) I tried someone's tip online to replace with backwards slashes, but that didn't work.